# SoundCloud authenticating using the Javascript SDK and phonegap

Tags: authentication, cordova, soundcloud

I am having difficulty authenticating (or finding any detailed documentation) with SoundClouds JavaScript SDK.  In the documentation https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#authentication it mentions a callback url but it states that if you are developing for mobile you can use a redirect_uri with a custom protocol scheme and set your app as a handler for that protocol scheme. For example, your redirect_uri could be something like my-app://soundcloud/callback.

It also says that you should use the options display=popup so that the right log in screen is presented.  This is what I have tried to implement but it is not working.  Does anybody know what is wrong with this?

```
SC.initialize({
    client_id: 'MY_CLIENT_ID',
    redirect_uri: 'icipici://soundcloud/callback'

});

$('.connect').on("click", function(){
    SC.connect(function() {
        SC.get('/me','display=popup', function(me) {
            alert('Hello, ' + me.username);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it completely, but think it is the right direction.
You have to:

1. Register a custom URL schema like explained [here](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html) (for iOS, I haven't used Android for the moment).
2. Modify the redirect_url in your SoundCloud App config: http://soundcloud.com/you/apps/ (in your case `icipici://soundcloud/callback`)
3. Modify SC.initialize with the same redirect_uri
4. Implement the handler to return the callback html page. Or maybe something else (invoke callback directly?), not sure. Here is where I reached. It probably have to be written in Objective-C as explained in the link indicated in point 1, so not sure how to manage it in Phonegap.